# How to change wordpress port number to 8000?

Tags: apache

I followed instructions on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334094/changing-port-number-in-wordpress-blog), however, it didn't help!

And I also changed apache listening port number to 8000. But it didn't work.

How can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: What is your current WordPress url? Check in **Dashboard > Settings** or in `phpMyAdmin` **> Your DB > wp_options > siteurl**. Also, let us know if you can access your apache with `http://localhost/` or `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: Imho is the problem not WordPress but a Server setting you want to change and therefore not on topic here on WPSE.

Comment: @Charles server configuration for WP is considered in scope here.